# Determine rate of level build up in horizontal cylinder when given volumetric flow rate.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A horizontal cylinder with diameter $D$ and length $L$ is being filled up with liquid at a rate of $Q$.

The height of liquid level inside the horizontal cylinder is $h$.

The volume of liquid is $$V=LA$$ $$V=L\left[\frac{\pi{D^2}}4-\frac{D^2}4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{D-2h}D\right)+\frac{D-2h}2\sqrt{Dh-h^2}\right]$$

The volumetric flowrate $Q$ is equal to the volume build up $\frac{dV}{dt}$
$$Q=\frac{dV}{dt}$$

I would like to find out the rate of level build up in relation to the volumetric flow rate.

$$\frac{dh}{dt}=\left(\frac{dV}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dh}{dV}\right)$$

Am I right so far?

To find $\frac{dh}{dV}$, I have to express $h$ in terms of $V$.

$$\frac{D-2h}2\sqrt{Dh-h^2}-\frac{D^2}4\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{D-2h}D\right)=\frac{V}L-\frac{\pi{D^2}}4$$

From here onwards I'm not sure how to progress. Appreciate kind help. Thanks!

Comment: Why not to compute $\frac{dV}{dh}$ ?

Comment: Does it work that way? So $\frac{dh}{dt}=\left(\frac{dV}{dt}\right)/\left(\frac{dV}{dh}\right)$?

Comment: Yes, for sure !